# Como puedo reproducir un archivo mp3 que se encuentre alojado en Google drive en Android Estudio?

Tags: audio, mp3

Estoy necesitando reproducir unos archivos mp3 que los tengo alojados en Google Drive en Android Studio?. Que me pueden sugerir para programarlo en java.

Answer (score 0):

Para reproducir mp3 en android studio se usa MediaPlayer, la clase de Android para reproducir audios. Te recomiendo que te leas la documentación:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

```
//reproducir desde url de drive
    public void playURL(){
        //Link de drive
        String finalURL = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cEhQvS5Nmnsynvlt44EYhi3cdWC-tSJX";

        if (player == null){
            Log.d(Constants.AUDIO_LOG_TAG, "Archivo mp4 no encontrado");
            return;
        }
        try {
           player.reset();
            Log.d(Constants.AUDIO_LOG_TAG, "Reproduciendo desde : " + finalURL);
            player.setDataSource(finalURL);
            player.prepareAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.AUDIO_LOG_TAG, "Error al reproducir el archivo " + finalURL, e);
        }
```